# Creating a Circular Slider/Carousel with a Similar Design to pango.co.il using reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a circular slider/carousel similar to the one featured on [pango.co.il.](https://www.pango.co.il/) However, I'm facing challenges in achieving the desired design and functionality.

Specifically, here are the issues I'm facing:

1. The slides are not arranged in a perfect circle.
2. The active slide is not centered and larger than the other slides.
3. The previous and next slides are not positioned slightly further away and scaled down.
4. The rotation and perspective effect of the circular arrangement are not as expected.

I have created a demo on CodeSandbox to showcase my current implementation: [Link to Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-chatterjee-gg7q2s?file=/src/App.js)

[Desired Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX9LZ.png)
In the image, you can see the desired appearance of the circular slider/carousel from Pango.co.il. I would like to achieve a similar design and functionality in my implementation.

I would appreciate any guidance or assistance in modifying the code to achieve a circular slider/carousel that closely resembles the one on pango.co.il. Suggestions for alternative approaches or libraries are also welcome.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex question since it's about a complex UI :)

However, I'd go along with these few guidelines:

1. Think of a state management logic that'll allow maintaining both the order of the options and the currently selected option.
2. If the desired result is circular motion, `transform: rotate()` might be the most straightforward implementation.
3. The challenge would be keeping all the options horizontal (i.e. parallel to the screenview). Think of a way to maintain the angle of each option.
4. The center component will be easy to implement, once the rest is working.

Good luck!